# Lookup Filter is not showing object fields to create a filter

Tags: lookup-filter

I am trying to put a filter on a lookup field so that i can only show the records which will full fill the filter criteria. But in during the setiap of filter criteria i am not able to get all the custom fields in filter criteria to add filter logic. I have checked the fls permission as well and its allowed to system admin. Can anyone please suggest me how i can get the fields in filter criteria.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Lookup field filters [do not support all field types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_limitations.htm&type=5). Specifically,

> Lookup filter criteria can’t reference these types of fields on the source object:
>
> - Autonumber
> - Encrypted
> - Formula
> - Long text area
> - Multi-select picklist
> - Roll-up summary
> - Text
> - Text area
> - URL

Salesforce [recommends the use of validation rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&type=5) if you have a use case that lookup filters don't support, such as the above, or needing to reference a relationship field from the source object or more than one relationship deep on the target object.